# C++: how to stop compilers from spamming errors with large template parameters?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

In my C++ code which depends heavily on template metaprogramming I have something like that:

```
template <int TFoo, int TBar, int TBaz, int TQux, typename TSpam>
struct MyClassConfig {
    static int const Foo = TFoo;
    static int const Bar = TBar;
    static int const Baz = TBaz;
    static int const Qux = TQux;
    using Spam = TSpam;
};

template <typename Config>
class MyClass {
    ...
};
```

That is, I use dummy classes to contain various parameters. Here, there's usually a lot of nesting, so `MyClassConfig::Spam` could again be such a configuration class.

This all works until the compiler (g++) decides it doesn't like my code. At this point it will happily print out the entire `MyClassConfig` at any chance it gets. Combined with other forms of metaprogramming used, the error messages then explode into megabytes.

**EDIT** To make it more clear what's happening, see [my actual code](https://github.com/ambrop72/aprinter/blob/master/aprinter/printer/aprinter-ramps13.cpp#L190) and [a typical error output](http://pastebin.com/dgPqqsfT). The first link points to my giant configuration type aliased as `PrinterParams` which is then given as a template parameter to `PrinterMain<>`. See how the error output is 99% composed of this configuration type being blown out in its full glory. I believe the error would be much more readable if only the `PrinterParams` would be kept in alias form instead of being expanded by the compiler.

Comment: It looks to me like you are abusing templates.

Comment: Enter the [error competition](http://tgceec.tumblr.com/)?

Comment: You could use external tools like [TextFilt](http://textfilt.sourceforge.net/) to improve error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/656420/318716

Comment: Maybe the external tool [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the newest version of GCC you can get. The GCC guys improved their error messages a lot. Especially 4.8 formatted them better and the future 4.9 added color to it. Looking back I am wondering how I could ever use GCC 4.4 or older.

If you can switch to clang, they have superior error messages. Clang is a major driving force for GCC to improve the error messages.

But in your case I think Robert Harvey is right. Your example looks like template abuse.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for calling C++ Standard Committee. Due to unusually heavy call volume, we are experiencing longer-than-normal delays in answering your call. We apologize for this inconvenience. Your call is important for us. Please stay on the line.

(Funny hat off)

The exploding error messages problem was, and still is, a major bane of C++ library writers and users. There's no satisfactory solution. [Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) were slated to be the solution in C++11, but concepts were scraped at the last minute. [Concepts Lite](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s) may or may not enter C++1y. As of now (C+11), library writers are left with [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert), but this requires thoughtful application by hand. Manual labour, boo! To use `static_assert`, you, the library writer, do the following:

1. Write down *all* requirements that template arguments must satisfy.
2. For each requirement, create a boolean-valued compile-time function (`constexpr` or plain old `type<arg>::value`) that is true when the requirement is satisfied.
3. Use all these functions in `static_assert` declarations in each template instantiateable by the user.

Apply these procedures religiously, and you just might have a chance of producing readable error messages that do not explode to megabytes.

Below is a hastily thrown together example of how this could be done. Compile it with g++ and see what happens. Only remember that it's not ready for production ;) No attempt has been made to deal with references, rvalue references, and `const`. Note that clang++ reports `static_assert` *and* all the other errors it finds in a function, which sort of defeats its purpose; while g++ reports only `static_assert`s. So for clang++ we additionally need to suppress the function body if any of the static asserts has fired; this is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T> struct supports_inequal
{
    template <class U> static auto test(const U u) -> decltype(bool(u != u), char(0)) { }
    static std::array<char, 2> test(...) { }
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == 1);
};

template <class T> struct supports_dereference
{
    template <class U> static auto test(const U u) -> decltype(*u, char(0)) { }
    static std::array<char, 2> test(...) { }
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == 1);
};

template <class T> struct supports_postincrement
{
    template <class U> static auto test(U u) -> decltype(u++, char(0)) { }
    static std::array<char, 2> test(...) { }
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == 1);
};

template <class T1, class T2> struct supports_assignment
{
    template <class U, class V> static auto postincrement_test(U u, const V v) -> decltype(*u = *v, char(0)) { }
    static std::array<char, 2> test(...) { }
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test(std::declval<T1>(),std::declval<T2>())) == 1);
};

template <typename It1, typename It2, typename It3>
void my_copy (It1 it1, It2 it2, It3 it3)
{
    // Check that It1 and It2 are the same type
    static_assert (std::is_same<It1, It2>::value, "\n\n\nArgument 1 and argument 2 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be of the same type\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_1 = std::is_same<It1, It2>::value;

    static_assert (!previous_assertions_1 || supports_inequal<It1>::value, "\n\n\nArgument 1 and argument 2 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be comparable with '!='\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_2 = previous_assertions_1 && supports_inequal<It1>::value;

    static_assert (!previous_assertions_2 || supports_dereference<It1>::value, "\n\n\nArguments 1 and 2 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be dereferenceable\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_3 = previous_assertions_2 && supports_dereference<It1>::value;

    static_assert (!previous_assertions_3 || supports_dereference<It3>::value, "\n\n\nArgument 3 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be dereferenceable\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_4 = previous_assertions_3 && supports_dereference<It3>::value;

    static_assert (!previous_assertions_4 || supports_postincrement<It1>::value, "\n\n\nArguments 1 and 2 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be postincrementable\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_5 = previous_assertions_4 && supports_postincrement<It1>::value;

    static_assert (!previous_assertions_5 || supports_dereference<It3>::value, "\n\n\nArgument 3 and of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be postincrementable\n\n\n");
    static const bool previous_assertions_6 = previous_assertions_4 && supports_postincrement<It3>::value;

    std::copy (it1, it2, it3); // g++ does not complain here when static_assert fires, clang++ does (QoI issue": we have staic assert so that we could control the error messages!)
}

struct A {};

int main ()
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    my_copy(a, b, c); // no error
    std::copy(a, b, c); // no error
    my_copy(a, b, A()); // human readable error message: argument 3 of my_copy(it1, it2, it3) must be dereferenceable
    std::copy(a, b, A()); // stack of incomprehensible error messages : "\n\n\nerror: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<A>’"?
}
```

Comment: But surely you are aware that static_assert will produce an error message just as well ;)

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak You do want to emit an error message when the user makes an error, right? `static_assert` will emit *an* error message, not a multimegabyte explosion. And it will be an error message that *you* want, crafted in terms of the interface used, and not in terms of its *implementation*.

Comment: Static assert will produce a "template backtrace" just as well. Static assert is just another way to cause an error, it won't make the error any more pretty.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: That's essentially a UI problem. The full stack of a regular assertion is typically just as big, it's just presented in a way that allows for easy browsing.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak Look at it and judge for yourself which is more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution is to use meta-functions:

```
template <int TFoo, int TBar, int TBaz, int TQux, typename TSpam>
struct MyClassConfig { };

template <int TFoo, int TBar, int TBaz, int TQux, typename TSpam>
constexpr int FooOf(MyClassConfig<TFoo, TBar, TBaz, TQux, TSpam>) {
    return TFoo;
};


using currentConfig = MyClassConfig<1,2,3,4, float>;
const int currentFoo = FooOf(currentConfig()); // = 1
```

Because `FooOf` isn't a member of `MyClassConfig`, that class stays a lot smaller.

Comment: The problem isn't about printing the members of MyClassConfig, those aren't printed automaticaly. But its template parameters are. Whenever MyClass is involved in an error somehow, the compiler will say "MyClass<MyClassConfig<LOTS_OF_TEXT>>". As far as I can see your constexpr functions dont't fix than, and actually introduce quadratic code growth. That is, for every new MyClassConfig parameter you need to write a new function *and* type it twice in all the existing functions.