# Shortening GCC error messages

Tags: c++, gcc

Whenever `gcc` can't find a matching overload for a function with multiple overloads, it gives lines and lines of errors, explaining which overload was tried and why it was not used.

While often it is useful, it is also often not, as the problem as a simple typo at the call site. And in this particular case, it is not even helpful, because it will take considerable time to even find out which line is ultimately responsible for this issue.

Is there any command line switch to GCC to shorten the output and only include the actual triggering line? For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Z{};

void foo() {

    std::string s;
    Z z;

    std::cout << z; // typo - meant s 
}
```

See error output: https://godbolt.org/g/wz5vL2

**Small addition**: third party solutions (STLFilt, gccfilter, etc) do not fit the bill, because a) my work environment is not welcoming towards installing 3rd party apps and b) they tend to become unmaintained and stop working with the next compiler upgrade

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656420/is-there-any-way-to-get-readable-gcc-error-and-warning-output-at-the-command-lin) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928244/how-to-hide-defaulted-template-parameters-in-gcc-error-messages).

Comment: Just grep your `filename.cpp:`... (of course this is not a "command line switch to GCC")

Comment: Better grep gcc's output: `g++ filename.cpp -fdiagnostics-color=always | head -30`.

Comment: The first error message that appears for this error is `<source>:11:15: error: no match for 'operator<<'`, which seems pretty straightforward and gives the location in your code. There are cases where it's hard to find where the error is from the message but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @interjay, yes, I just couldn't quickly construct MCVE with those. There are cases when the actual error line could only be seen in like `required from here` message.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/13025773/27302 help? I’m reluctant to close as a duplicate in case `gccfilter` hasn’t been maintained or you need a flag for some reason, but it might work. Failing that the only other option I found was https://stackoverflow.com/q/11313600/27302, and I hope there’s a better solution by now.

Comment: @DanielH no, gccfilter doesn't help, because I work in environment where installing 3rd-party extra apps is problematic.

Comment: "it will take considerable time to even find out which line is ultimately responsible for this issue" - not really. With `-fdiagnostics-color=always` corresponding line is colored in red and can be found relatively easy.

Comment: The "required from here" message appears when you're using templates. Like this: https://godbolt.org/g/d9gqtX. The problem is that there's no way for the compiler to know if the typo was in the template or the code which uses it, so it shows both. If you had a solution that hides one of them, it might hide the actual culprit.

Comment: @interjay Certainly, this is why it could be a switch and people could use it... On any rate, no means no.

Comment: Here's a common trick : the existence of tools often points to the need for those tools. If tool Y takes the output of tool X to do some operation Foo, then presumably Y was created because X can't do Foo. So substitute X=gcc, Y=gccfilter, and Foo=this question. That givs us the answer, "no, gcc can't do what gccfilter does, else why would gccfilter exist?"

Comment: @MSalters not really, especially in open source domain. First of, gcc filter is old. Something could pop along. Second off, people who were doing gccfilter might have had their reasons.

Answer (score 10):

One way is to use `-Wfatal-errors`.  It changes the error message from

```
<source>: In function 'void foo()':

<source>:11:15: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Z')

     std::cout << z; // typo - meant s

     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/iostream:39:0,

                 from <source>:2:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]

       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))

many more lines of errors
```

to

```
    <source>: In function 'void foo()':

<source>:11:15: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Z')

     std::cout << z; // typo - meant s

     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Compiler returned: 1
```

The only downside is you will only get the first error.  If your compile times are long then this isn't the greatest as you wouldn't be able to fix any other errors until you fix that first one and recompile.

Comment: Yes, I agree with fatal errors being a partial solution. Upvoting, but not accepting :D

Comment: @SergeyA I totally understand.  I'm not sure I would accept this either unless there really isn't any other compiler flag.